# Headset microphone not working

Tags: linux-mint, microphone, headset

- Laptop: Lenovo-B490 have single port 3.5mm(LinuxMint 19 Cinnamon)
- Headset: Remax-610D have single jack 3.5mm also

when plug-in together, I can use my headset to listening music, but microphone seems doesn't work.

> System Setting → Sound → Input → **just show** Internal Microphone Built-In Audio

I tried to speak near laptop then sound bar is moving, when I speak near headset the sound bar didn't response.

How do I get my headset's microphone to work?

Comment: Did you change the hardware configuration to reflect an external mic?

Comment: No. I don't do anything. It works on windows 10 a week ago before I move to Mint.